# In ionic app I want to open all links from server with InAppBrowser

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4, inappbrowser

In ionic `inappbrowser` i want to open all url links which are unknown from the server to open inside `_blank ionic inappbrowser`. The problem is if we know the url we can pass like `('url', '_blank', 'options')` but the links are coming from the serve obviously we don't know the url so is there any solution for this

```
import { InAppBrowser } from '@ionic-native/in-app-browser/ngx'

constructor(private iab: InAppBrowser)
```

Comment: why can't you use the the url even if it is coming from the server?

Comment: i don't know how please could you tell.

Comment: share some code. How you are calling the api? I will tell you how you can use it in in-app-browser.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming few things here as not much code is available,

```
class DemoComponent {

apiResponse : any
constructor(private iab: InAppBrowser, private api : RestService){
    this.callApi().subscribe( data => {
        // Response is array of string
        // ['https://www.google.com','https://www.facebook.com','https://www.example.com]
        const firstLinkFromResponse = data[0];
        this.openBrowser( firstLinkFromResponse );
    });
}

callApi() {
    return new Observable(observer => {
        // call api here
        const serverResponse = ['https://www.google.com','https://www.facebook.com','https://www.example.com];
        observer.next(serverResponse);
    })
}

openBrowser(link : string) {
    const browser = this.iab.create(link);
    browser.show();
    browser.on('loadstop').subscribe(event => {
        console.log('Link successfully opened');
    });
}

}
```